# How to evaluate these complex integrals?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to learn string theory in AdS. Following this review:
 https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2604, I have come across the following integrals when trying to calculate some OPEs:

$$
I = \int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{ d^{2} u }{(u - w)^{2} (u - z)}.
$$

The author claims on page 137, equation (D.4), that

$$
I = - 2 \pi \frac{\bar{z} - \bar{w}}{(z - w)^{2}}.
$$

How is this possible? I have no idea how to compute this, or even how to
search for it in the literature. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) is your friend.

Comment: How? I don't see how this is an application of Cauchy's formula. How do you get the $\bar{z}$ dependence? Please, post an answer.

Comment: I am resisting the temptation to work it out, so maybe I'm wrong.  But since you're integrating over the plane, you could combine Cauchy with an improper integral out to $\infty$.

Comment: If you know Cauchy's formula, please include to the post your attempts to apply this formula to solve the present problem.

Comment: I do not know if are asking me or Matthew. If you are asking me, I don't think that I can use Cauchy's formula. The integrand is not holormorphic in $u$: $\bar{\partial}_{u} (u - z)^{-1} = \delta^{2} (u - z)$ and $\bar{\partial}_{u} (u - w)^{-2} = - \partial_{u} \delta^{2} ( u - w)$.

Comment: Sorry but are you saying that the function $$u\mapsto\frac1{(u-w)^2(u-z)}$$ is not holomorphic on $$\mathbb C\setminus\{w,z\}\ ?$$ (Your comment stating this just got upvoted... I guess this is a good news, since now, one user which is not you can also explain.)

Answer (score -1):

I have found a way. It is likely to be incorrect, but it reproduces all integrals of the paper.

Define

$$
I  = \int \frac{d^{2} u}{(u - w)^{2} (u -z)}
$$

and take

$$
\frac{\partial I}{ \partial \bar{z}} = - 2 \pi\int \frac{d^{2} u}{(u-w)^{2}} \delta^{2} (u-z) = - 2 \pi \frac{1}{(z - w)^{2}}.
$$

The same way, compute

$$
\frac{\partial I}{\partial \bar{w}} = -2 \pi \frac{\partial}{\partial w}\int \frac{d^{2}u}{(u-z)} \delta^{2} (u - w) =   2 \pi \frac{1}{(z - w)^{2}}.$$

It follows then

$$
I = - 2 \pi \frac{\bar{z} - \bar{w}}{(z-w)^{2}}.
$$

Notice that

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} \left[ \frac{\bar{z}}{(z-w)^{2}} \right]
=  \frac{1}{(z-w)^{2}} - \bar{z} \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\, \delta^{2} (z-w) = \frac{1}{(z-w)^{2}}
$$

because the delta multiplies the odd function $\bar{z}$.

If someone knows a way to obtain this result in any other way, please post it.